# IE7-8 gradient and less css

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, less, gradient

I'm trying to add a gradient effect on a button. I'm using Less syntax.

I currently apply this to my element :

filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffeaa5', endColorstr='#f8b000',GradientType=0 )";

But no gradient is shown on my button. Any idea?

Thank you.

edit : it works on this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FBfSZ/
but not on this page : http://canapin.com/web/ (look at the source)

I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's because your page is not a valid HTML page, so the IE switches to the quirks mode. You can easily see it yourself, when you press `F12`, to get the developer mode.

Create a valid HTML page, with doctype, header element and all the like, i think it should work then.

Answer (score 1):

try this I test it on IE 8

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffeaa5', endColorstr='#f8b000',GradientType=0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in IE8, it comes from twitter bootstrap

```
filter: e(%("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='%d',
 endColorstr='%d', GradientType=0)",#ffeaa5,#f8b000)); // IE9 and down
```